# How van unistall completely gimp from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: uninstall, gimp

I've install gimp easily with apt-get install gimp.
This installed also a lot of files, I'm wonder why there is an easy way to uninstall like to install it.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get purge gimp`?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt purge gimp
```

Maybe followed by

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

The latter will remove any unused and obsolete packages - check the output before hitting *y* for yes.